# Java computer to computer connection?

Tags: java, port, connect, tcp

Is it possible to have two computers socket-connect to each other without any server involved in Java?  If so, how?  I've only seen examples of server-client connections where the server is permanent.

For example:

```
1. 2 people, person A and person B, want to connect using this application
2. Person A runs application, clicks "host"
3. Application hands person A a code (IP+port?) and begins listening.
4. Person B clicks "join" and types in code.
5.  Person B's computer sees Person A's computer and they connect. Person A accepts connection.
```

I've never really understood this well.  Please pardon me if this is a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scenario, person A's PC would be acting as the server and person B's would be acting as the client. Even if it is only temporary, the fact that A is *listening* for a connection means that it is acting as a server.

Comment: Okay.  So you could just find your external IP, listen on port xxxx, and send them the code IP:port, and there would be no objections, provided the client handles it correctly?

Comment: There might be further considerations depending on where A and B are located. If A and B are on the same network, A can just advertise the local IP. But if they are not on the same network and there is NAT translation going on (both A and B have external internet IPs), you may need a server after all. There is no easy way of getting your external IP without a server, unless it is static and you know it in advance.

Comment: I think I'll just make a server that echoes your IP.  Why isn't there some official IP lookup tool?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to determine your external IP, which may vary depending on who the receiver is. For example, lets say  person A is connected to their router, which is also connected to two distinct networks X and Y that are only connected by A's router. A's router has a different IP on each of these networks. If person B is on network X, then he will need to connect to A router's IP for network X. If person B is on network Y, he will need A router's IP for network Y.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, one side has to initiate the connection (i.e. issue the connect request).  That means the other side has to have a server socket open to receive the connection.  You could use the same code on both sides by making both implement client and server functionality, and assume the appropriate role (server or client) depending on which user initiates the connection.